# sock_sendmsg(): implicit function calls by Kernel

Tags: linux, sockets, kernel, system-calls, systemtap

I tried to dump all data sent by a specific process on Linux by hooking a handler to the Kernel's function `sock_sendmsg()` defined in `linux/socket.c`.
I could do that by writing a systemtap probe handler for `probe kernel.function("sock_sendmsg@net/socket.c")` that dumps all data blocks passed with the 2nd argument `struct msghdr *msg`.

Here's the excerpt from `net/socket.c`:

```
int sock_sendmsg(struct socket *sock, struct msghdr *msg, size_t size)
{
    struct kiocb iocb;
    struct sock_iocb siocb;
    int ret;

    init_sync_kiocb(&iocb, NULL);
    iocb.private = &siocb;
    ret = __sock_sendmsg(&iocb, sock, msg, size);
    if (-EIOCBQUEUED == ret)
            ret = wait_on_sync_kiocb(&iocb);
    return ret;
}
```

I tested my systemtap script `hook_sendmsg.stp`. First I ran `hook_sendmsg.stp` in one terminal. Then I opened another terminal and invoked `telnet` command to connect to `stackoverflow.com` and typed `HEAD / HTTP/1.0<Enter twice>` in the terminal. I got the following output from `hook_sendmsg.stp`:

```
root@debian:~# stap -g hook_sendmsg.stp
message block [0]; type=3(raw); state=1(unconnected)
14 00 00 00 16 00 01 03 ec 95 f4 52 00 00 00 00 |...........R....|
00 00 00 00                                     |................|
message block [0]; type=3(raw); state=1(unconnected)
14 00 00 00 16 00 01 03 ec 95 f4 52 00 00 00 00 |...........R....|
00 00 00 00                                     |................|
message block [0]; type=2(udp); state=1(unconnected)
4d 0d 01 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 0d 73 74 61 |M............sta|
63 6b 6f 76 65 72 66 6c 6f 77 03 63 6f 6d 00 00 |ckoverflow.com..|
01 00 01                                        |................|
message block [0]; type=2(udp); state=1(unconnected)
0f 1e 01 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 0d 73 74 61 |.............sta|
63 6b 6f 76 65 72 66 6c 6f 77 03 63 6f 6d 00 00 |ckoverflow.com..|
1c 00 01                                        |................|
message block [0]; type=1(tcp); state=3(connected)
48 45 41 44 20 2f 20 48 54 54 50 2f 31 2e 30 0d |HEAD / HTTP/1.0.|
0a                                              |................|
message block [0]; type=1(tcp); state=3(connected)
0d 0a                                           |................|
```

This shows that totally `sock_sendmsg()` were called 6 times in the context of `telnet`. Obviously the 3rd and 4th are DNS queries to Google's public DNS servers `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4`. The 5th and 6th are the two lines of HTTP request sent from `telnet`. But what were the 1st and 2nd called for? Did they called internally by the Kernel?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can add a print_backtrace(); print_ubacktrace(); pair to the probe handler to get a sense of what's going on.  Add "-d /usr/bin/telnet --ldd -d kernel" to the stap command line to enable fuller backtracing.

Comment: Thanks, fche. Useful tips for Kernel debugging. I tried those functions but `print_ubacktrace()` didn't work. It seems Debian doesn't enable `CONFIG_UTRACE` option by default. I have to recompile the Kernel.

Comment: Hm, I don't think you should need CONFIG_UPROBES just for print_ubacktrace().  If you're sure, please send us some details on the mailing list.

Comment: Thanks. The following is the error message I got when I tried to insert `print_ubacktrace()`: `user-space facilities not available without kernel CONFIG_UTRACE`. In my environment `print_ubacktrace()` is defined in `tapset/ucontext-unwind.stp` and include `/* pragma:uprobes */`, so I'm pretty sure `print_ubacktrace()` needs `CONFIG_UPROBES`.

Comment: Right you are, Alice.  We're investigating why that pragma thingie is still there.  You could try removing it (to beat us to the testing).

Comment: Yes. It worked without `pragma:uprobes`. It printed some addresses of instructions right after `syscall` function calls. Unlike `print_backtrace()`, it only printed addresses and not function names.

Comment: Add the "stap -d /usr/bin/telnet --ldd" options and try again.

Comment: Thanks. It worked as expected on Fedora (Kernel 3.12 with uprobes enabled), but didn't on Debian (Kernel 3.2 with uprobes disabled). Does uprobes feature needed for `print_ubacktrace()` to work properly? BTW, when I invoked `stap` command on Fedora with those options, the following message was printed: `WARNING: Missing unwind data for module, rerun with 'stap -d /usr/lib64/libnss_dns-2.18.so'`. Doesn't `--ldd` options unwind shared libraries automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are NETLINK messages, as you can see if you monitor the telnet command from userspace with strace (check the socket family):

```
sendto(3, "\24\0\0\0\26\0\1\3?\254\364R\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 20, 0, {sa_family=AF_NETLINK,  pid=0, groups=00000000}, 12) = 20
sendto(3, "\24\0\0\0\26\0\1\3?\254\364R\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 20, 0, {sa_family=AF_NETLINK, pid=0, groups=00000000}, 12) = 20
send(3, "\212\355\1\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\rstackoverflow\3com\0\0"..., 35, MSG_NOSIGNAL) = 35
send(3, "\241\353\1\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\rstackoverflow\3com\10i"..., 50, MSG_NOSIGNAL) = 50
send(3, "|\341\1\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\rstackoverflow\3com\0\0"..., 35, MSG_NOSIGNAL) = 35
send(3, "HEAD / HTTP/1.0\r\n", 17, 0)   = 17
send(3, "\r\n", 2, 0)                   = 2
```

Netlink is an interface used by the userspace processes to communicate with kernel (so, they are send by the telnet), usually for routing, firewalling... pourposes [1]. Some usual network C functions (i.e. getsockname) works internally with this kind of NETLINK messages.

If you want to investigate a bit more you should translate the payload of the send_message to the netlink header structure and check what type of messages are.:

```
       struct nlmsghdr {
           __u32 nlmsg_len;    /* Length of message including header. */
           __u16 nlmsg_type;   /* Type of message content. */
           __u16 nlmsg_flags;  /* Additional flags. */
           __u32 nlmsg_seq;    /* Sequence number. */
           __u32 nlmsg_pid;    /* Sender port ID. */
       };
```

[1]http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/netlink.7.html

Comment: Specifically, glibc's getaddrinfo() uses its internal __check_pf() function to check whether ipv4 and/or ipv6 interfaces exist on the system.

Comment: Thanks, Jon. I didn't know much about NETLINK, but it's interesting that NETLINK is used internally by some standard library functions.